# Create filter based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a function which scans the top row and inserts a filter on a particular cell in the third row if the corresponding cell in the top row contains a value.

If a cell is empty then it should skip to the next cell. The third row will be a header row.

Here is some of my code:

```vb
Sub FilterRefresh()
Dim i As Long, lastCol As Long
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim wSheet As Worksheet

Set wSheet = Worksheets("Machining")
'find the last column in row one
lastCol = wSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column 'xlToLeft

'set range from A1 to last column
Set rng = wSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, lastCol)) 'will be a higher cell range

'Outline the autofilter field hierarchy
i = 1
   For Each cell In rng
      If cell.Value <> "" Then
          wSheet.Cells(cell.row + 2, i + 1).AutoFilter Field:=i, Criteria1:=cell.Value 
          i = i + 1
      End If
   Next cell
End Sub
```

It creates filters for the first three header cells regardless of what is in the cell above.

Comment: You may get more help if you explain not just what you want the code to do, but what the code you are using is currently doing wrong..

Comment: When i execute the function it just creates filters for the first three header cells regardless of what is in the cell above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
For Each cell In rng
  If cell.Value <> "" Then
      wSheet.Cells(cell.Row + 2, cell.Column).AutoFilter Field:=cell.Column, Criteria1:=cell.Value
  End If
Next cell
```

Comment: The issue was your `i = i + 1` increments only if there was something there (it was inside your `If.. EndIf` block) so it wasn't in line with the tested column. If it was after the `EndIf` it would've also worked. But the above code does away with the need for an `i` altogether.